# Функции, возвращающие указатели

Tags: c, указатели

Допустим, есть функция (вята из книги Ритчи)

```
#define ALLOCSIZE 10000 /* размер доступного пространства */
static char allocbuf[ALLOCSIZE]; /* память для alloc */
static char *allocp = allocbuf; /* указатель на своб. место */

    char *alloc(int n) /* возвращает указатель на n символов */
{
if (allocbuf + ALLOCSIZE - allocp >= n) {
allocp += n; /* пространство есть */
return allocp - n; /* старое р */
} else /* пространства нет */
return 0;
}
```

У меня возникает недопонимание, насчет звездочки в объявлении функции. Когда мы создаем в мейне указатель и вызываем для него функцию

```
    int main(){
char *p;
p = alloc(3);
}
```

то, если рассмотреть данный вызов дословно, то му получим так (если я не ошибаюсь)

```
p = (allocp-3);
```

а не так

```
p = *(allocp-3);
```

Вот меня мучает эта звездочка, я не совсем понимаю как она работает(именно в функции). Это просто пунктуация или создается указатель *alloc, затем присваивается адрес из массива и происходит присваивание указетеля указетялю p = alloc. Или возвращается само значение. Или что другое. Объясните, пожалуйста, если поняли суть моего вопроса.

p.s что значит эта звездочка я знаю, я не совсем понимаю как она работает в данной функции

Comment: Непонятно, что вас смущает? `p` - указатель, `allocp` - указатель. Зачем его разыменовывать, как вы предлагаете - `p = *(allocp-3);`?

Comment: @Harry Я не понимаю зачем нам * в функции alloc, если мы все равно возвращаем указатель allocp

Comment: Какая именно звездочка? В теле функции вообще ни одной звездочки (кроме как в комментариях...)

Comment: @Harry char *alloc(int n){....}

Comment: Ну функция ведь возвращает *указатель* типа `char*`, а не символ? Вот звездочка и использована для указания на этот факт - возврат указателя...

Comment: "Я не понимаю зачем нам `*` в функции `alloc`, если мы все равно возвращаем указатель `allocp`". Нуууу..., тип выражения `allocp - n` действительно `char *`, но в функция `alloc` также есть строчка `return 0;`. Как компилятор поймёт, значение какого именно типа вы хотите вернуть из функции? Хотите ли вы вернуть значение типа `char *`? А может вы хотите вернуть из функции значение типа `int`? Для того, чтобы помочь компилятору, перед именем функции и указывается тип возвращаемого значения.

Comment: @wololo а если мы будем возвращать 0, хоть перед функцией и будет стоять char *, то будет все нормально(если я не ошибаюсь), а если мы попытаемся вернуть другое число 1-9, то что будет тогда?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы указываете звездочке в объявлении - вы указываете, что тип данных - указатель. Когда же вы указываете ее вне объявления - это разыменовывание, т.е. получение данных по адресу, на который указывает этот указатель. Так что ф-ция возвращает не данные, находящиеся по данному адресу - а адрес памяти, указывающий на соответствующий тип данных. Если вы разименуете его, то получите данные, находящиеся по данному адресу.

если ф-ция возвращает указатель на число `int`

```
int *p = malloc (sizeof *p);
*p = *(fun (3));
```

a можно и

```
int *p = NULL;
p = fun (3);
```

в `*p` будет тоже число в обоих случаях, но вот `p` будет разным.